# SIP Register Request using JAIN SIP

Tags: java, jain-sip

I try to develop a sipPhone for the project of the end of study .Now, I still stick in how can I register to Asterisk 1.8 server with authentication. I downloaded this code from [here](http://vkslabs.com/sip-register-request-using-jain-sip/):

```
package examples.authorization;

import gov.nist.javax.sip.Utils;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sip.ClientTransaction;
import javax.sip.Dialog;
import javax.sip.DialogTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.IOExceptionEvent;
import javax.sip.ListeningPoint;
import javax.sip.RequestEvent;
import javax.sip.ResponseEvent;
import javax.sip.SipFactory;
import javax.sip.SipListener;
import javax.sip.SipProvider;
import javax.sip.SipStack;
import javax.sip.TimeoutEvent;
import javax.sip.TransactionTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.address.Address;
import javax.sip.address.AddressFactory;
import javax.sip.header.AuthorizationHeader;
import javax.sip.header.CSeqHeader;
import javax.sip.header.CallIdHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ContactHeader;
import javax.sip.header.FromHeader;
import javax.sip.header.HeaderFactory;
import javax.sip.header.MaxForwardsHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ToHeader;
import javax.sip.header.ViaHeader;
import javax.sip.message.MessageFactory;
import javax.sip.message.Request;
import javax.sip.message.Response;


public class SipInit implements SipListener {


    private String ip;
    private SipFactory sipFactory;
    private Properties properties;
    private SipStack sipStack;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MessageFactory messageFactory;
    private HeaderFactory headerFactory;
    private AddressFactory addressFactory;
    private ListeningPoint listeningPoint;
    private int port;
    private String protocol;
    private SipProvider sipProvider;
    private String username;
    private Address contactAddress;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ContactHeader contactHeader;
    private String server;
    private char[] tag;
    private Request request;
    private String password;
    private ClientTransaction inviteTid;
    private Dialog dialog;

    public void init() {
        try {
            // Get the local IP address.
            this.ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            // Create the SIP factory and set the path name.
            this.sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
            this.sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
            // Create and set the SIP stack properties.
            this.properties = new Properties();
            this.properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "stack");
            this.properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.TRACE_LEVEL", "32");



            this.properties.setProperty(
                    "gov.nist.javax.sip.LOG_MESSAGE_CONTENT", "true");
            this.properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.DEBUG_LOG",
                    "mss-jsip-debuglog.txt");
            this.properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.SERVER_LOG",
                    "mss-jsip-messages.xml");
            // Create the SIP stack.
            this.sipStack = this.sipFactory.createSipStack(this.properties);
            // Create the SIP message factory.
            this.messageFactory = this.sipFactory.createMessageFactory();
            // Create the SIP header factory.
            this.headerFactory = this.sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
            // Create the SIP address factory.
            this.addressFactory = this.sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
            // Create the SIP listening point and bind it to the local IP
            // address, port and protocol.
            this.listeningPoint = this.sipStack.createListeningPoint(this.ip,
                    this.port, this.protocol);
            // Create the SIP provider.
            this.sipProvider = this.sipStack
                    .createSipProvider(this.listeningPoint);
            // Add our application as a SIP listener.
            this.sipProvider.addSipListener(this);
            // Create the contact address used for all SIP messages.
            this.contactAddress = this.addressFactory.createAddress("sip:" + this.username + "@"
                    + this.ip + ";transport=tcp");
            // Create the contact header used for all SIP messages.
            this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
                    .createContactHeader(contactAddress);
            // Display the local IP address and port in the text area.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // If an error occurs, display an error message box and exit.
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }


    public void register(Response response) {
        Object logger;
        try {
        int cseq;
        cseq++;
        ArrayList<ViaHeader> viaHeaders = new ArrayList<ViaHeader>();
        ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip,
        this.port, "tcp", null);
        viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
        // The "Max-Forwards" header.
        MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = this.headerFactory
        .createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
        // The "Call-Id" header.
        CallIdHeader callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
        // The "CSeq" header.
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = this.headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(cseq,
        "REGISTER");

        Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"
        + username + '@' + server);

        FromHeader fromHeader = this.headerFactory.createFromHeader(
        fromAddress, String.valueOf(this.tag));
        // The "To" header.
        ToHeader toHeader = this.headerFactory.createToHeader(fromAddress,
        null);

        // this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
        // .createContactHeader(contactAddress);

        request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("REGISTER sip:"
        + server + " SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n");
        request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
        request.addHeader(cSeqHeader);
        request.addHeader(fromHeader);
        request.addHeader(toHeader);
        request.addHeader(maxForwardsHeader);
        request.addHeader(viaHeader);
        request.addHeader(contactHeader);
        if (response != null) {
        boolean retry = true;
        AuthorizationHeader authHeader = Utils.makeAuthHeader(headerFactory, response,
        request, username, password);
        request.addHeader(authHeader);
        }
        inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
        // send the request out.
        inviteTid.sendRequest();
        this.dialog = inviteTid.getDialog();
        // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
//                  this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);

        // Display the message in the text area.
        ((Object) logger).debug("Request sent:\n" + request.toString() + "\n\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // If an error occurred, display the error.
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug("Request sent failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        }

    @Override
    public void processDialogTerminated(DialogTerminatedEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void processIOException(IOExceptionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void processRequest(RequestEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void processResponse(ResponseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void processTimeout(TimeoutEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void processTransactionTerminated(TransactionTerminatedEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

But I got this erro :

> The method makeAuthHeader(HeaderFactory, Response, Request, String,
>   String) is undefined for the type Utils

Could please help me  and Thanks.

Comment: Hello! I use the same code and the same error occurs. :S

Comment: No chance. Sorry I couldn't resolve the problem so I wait for someone who could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet might help - (used JAIN-Sip library - https://github.com/RestComm/jain-sip)

```
package com.sip.light.client;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

import javax.sip.ClientTransaction;
import javax.sip.DialogTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.IOExceptionEvent;
import javax.sip.InvalidArgumentException;
import javax.sip.ListeningPoint;
import javax.sip.ObjectInUseException;
import javax.sip.PeerUnavailableException;
import javax.sip.RequestEvent;
import javax.sip.ResponseEvent;
import javax.sip.SipException;
import javax.sip.SipFactory;
import javax.sip.SipProvider;
import javax.sip.TimeoutEvent;
import javax.sip.Transaction;
import javax.sip.TransactionTerminatedEvent;
import javax.sip.TransportNotSupportedException;
import javax.sip.address.AddressFactory;
import javax.sip.header.ContactHeader;
import javax.sip.header.HeaderFactory;
import javax.sip.message.MessageFactory;
import javax.sip.message.Request;
import javax.sip.message.Response;

import gov.nist.javax.sip.DialogTimeoutEvent;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.ListeningPointExt;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.SipListenerExt;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackExt;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.clientauthutils.AuthenticationHelper;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.clientauthutils.UserCredentials;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.NioMessageProcessorFactory;
import gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack;

public class SipClientLightSip implements SipListenerExt {
    private SipStackExt mSipStack;
    private HeaderFactory mHeaderFactory;
    private String mPeerHostPort;

    private AddressFactory mAddressFactory;
    private MessageFactory mMessageFactory;
    private ListeningPoint mUdpListeningPoint;
    private SipProvider mSipProvider;
    private int mUdpPort = 5082;
    private String mProtocol = "UDP";
   private String mIPAddress ="127.0.0.1"; // 
   // private String mIPAddress ="10.90.20.68"; //
    private UserCredentials mUserCredentials;
    private ContactHeader contactHeader;

    @Override
    public void processRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        System.out.println("RequestEvent "+requestEvent.getServerTransaction().getDialog());
    }

    @Override
    public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
        System.out.println("responseEvent.getResponse()" + responseEvent.getResponse());
        if(responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode() == Response.UNAUTHORIZED){

            AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper =
                    mSipStack.getAuthenticationHelper((challengedTransaction, realm) -> mUserCredentials, mHeaderFactory);
            try {

                authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(responseEvent.getResponse(),responseEvent.getClientTransaction(),mSipProvider,2000).sendRequest();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode() == Response.OK){
            System.out.println("responseEvent.getResponse()" + responseEvent.getResponse());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processTimeout(TimeoutEvent timeoutEvent) {
        Transaction transaction;
        if (timeoutEvent.isServerTransaction()) {
            transaction = timeoutEvent.getServerTransaction();
        } else {
            transaction = timeoutEvent.getClientTransaction();
            System.out.println(timeoutEvent.getTimeout().getValue());


        }
        System.out.println("state = " + transaction.getState());
        System.out.println("dialog = " + transaction.getDialog());
        System.out.println("Transaction Time out");
    }

    @Override
    public void processIOException(IOExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Expcetion occured "+exceptionEvent.getPort());
    }

    @Override
    public void processTransactionTerminated(TransactionTerminatedEvent transactionTerminatedEvent) {

            if (transactionTerminatedEvent.isServerTransaction())
                System.out.println("Transaction terminated event recieved"
                        + transactionTerminatedEvent.getServerTransaction());
            else {
                System.out.println("Transaction terminated "
                        + transactionTerminatedEvent.getClientTransaction());

                //System.out.println(transactionTerminatedEvent.getClientTransaction().getRequest());

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void processDialogTerminated(DialogTerminatedEvent dialogTerminatedEvent) {
        System.out.println("processDialogTerminated" +dialogTerminatedEvent);
    }


    public  void init() throws PeerUnavailableException, InvalidArgumentException, TransportNotSupportedException, ObjectInUseException, TooManyListenersException {
        SipFactory sipFactory = null;
        mSipStack = null;
        sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
        sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.setProperty("javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY", "127.0.0.1:5060" + "/"+ "ws");
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "SIP_CLIENT");

        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.TRACE_LEVEL", "32");
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.DEBUG_LOG", "sip_client/out/log/debug.txt");
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.SERVER_LOG", "sip_client/out/log/server.txt");
        //properties.setProperty("javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY","127.0.0.1:5082/WS");
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.IP_ADDRESS",mIPAddress);
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.TRANSPORT",mProtocol);
        //properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.USE_TLS_GATEWAY","true");
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.TCP_POST_PARSING_THREAD_POOL_SIZE", "1");
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.AUTOMATIC_DIALOG_SUPPORT", "off");
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.AUTOMATIC_DIALOG_ERROR_HANDLING","false");
        //properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.IS_BACK_TO_BACK_USER_AGENT","true");
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_FACTORY", NioMessageProcessorFactory.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("gov.nist.javax.sip.CACHE_CLIENT_CONNECTIONS","false");
        mSipStack = (SipStackExt) sipFactory.createSipStack(properties);


        mHeaderFactory = sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
        mAddressFactory = sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
        mMessageFactory = sipFactory.createMessageFactory();
        mUdpListeningPoint = mSipStack.createListeningPoint(mIPAddress, mUdpPort, mProtocol);

        mSipProvider = mSipStack.createSipProvider(mUdpListeningPoint);
        mSipProvider.addSipListener(this);

    }

    public void sendRegister(UserCredentials userCredentials,String serverIP,int serverPort) throws SipException, ParseException, InvalidArgumentException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("REGISTER sip:domain@127.0.0.1:5060;method=GET?Host=127.0.0.1&Location=/&transport="+mProtocol+" SIP/2.0\r\n");
    sb.append("CSeq: 1 REGISTER\r\n");
    sb.append("To: <sip:piyush@domain:5082>\r\n");
    sb.append("From: \"piyush\" <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=o3qshhkifd\r\n");
    sb.append("Call-ID: gth3knqa3t3n0bj42osph5\r\n");
    sb.append("Max-Forwards: 69\r\n");
    sb.append("Via: SIP/2.0/"+mProtocol+" n8020ls4d00s.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8197727\r\n");
    sb.append("Contact: <sip:6q93lp0l@n8020ls4d00s.invalid;transport="+mProtocol+">;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance=\"<urn:uuid:c8f8a859-5f68-48e4-88f4-49abf1ac036f>\";expires=600\r\n");

    sb.append("Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS\r\n");
    sb.append("Content-Length: 0\r\n");
    sb.append("Supported: path,gruu,outbound\r\n");
    sb.append("Expires: 600\r\n");


    System.out.println("Register request over websocket "+ request);




        ClientTransaction ctx = mSipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
        ctx.sendRequest();
        //timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 1000, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public void processDialogTimeout(DialogTimeoutEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}


/* Output as follows - 

Register request over websocket REGISTER sip:domain@127.0.0.1:5060;method=GET?Host=127.0.0.1&Location=/&transport=UDP SIP/2.0
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
To: <sip:piyush@domain:5082>
From: "piyush" <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=o3qshhkifd
Call-ID: gth3knqa3t3n0bj42osph5
Max-Forwards: 69
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP n8020ls4d00s.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8197727
Contact: <sip:6q93lp0l@n8020ls4d00s.invalid;transport=UDP>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:c8f8a859-5f68-48e4-88f4-49abf1ac036f>";expires=600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS
Supported: path,gruu,outbound
Expires: 600
Content-Length: 0


responseEvent.getResponse()SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
To: <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=6e9d37d85ef64ab7aee1dfb44a2b1f94
From: "piyush" <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=o3qshhkifd
Call-ID: gth3knqa3t3n0bj42osph5
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP n8020ls4d00s.invalid:5082;branch=z9hG4bK8197727
x-Error-Details: No auth header
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="domain",nonce="b97e036da02577c13598f26e4e3d27ec",qop="auth",algorithm=MD5,stale=false,opaque="00000001"
Content-Length: 0


responseEvent.getResponse()SIP/2.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
To: <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=68067566c18441ccb8a645c812aa23f1
From: "piyush" <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=o3qshhkifd
Call-ID: gth3knqa3t3n0bj42osph5
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP n8020ls4d00s.invalid:5082;branch=z9hG4bK-37-d3e9f8fe24da7121a13553b1b7c0b54d
Contact: <sip:6q93lp0l@n8020ls4d00s.invalid;transport=UDP>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:c8f8a859-5f68-48e4-88f4-49abf1ac036f>";expires=599
Expires: 599
Content-Length: 0


responseEvent.getResponse()SIP/2.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
To: <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=68067566c18441ccb8a645c812aa23f1
From: "piyush" <sip:piyush@domain:5082>;tag=o3qshhkifd
Call-ID: gth3knqa3t3n0bj42osph5
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP n8020ls4d00s.invalid:5082;branch=z9hG4bK-37-d3e9f8fe24da7121a13553b1b7c0b54d
Contact: <sip:6q93lp0l@n8020ls4d00s.invalid;transport=UDP>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:c8f8a859-5f68-48e4-88f4-49abf1ac036f>";expires=599
Expires: 599
Content-Length: 0


Transaction terminated gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPClientTransactionImpl@7c805a26
Transaction terminated gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPClientTransactionImpl@5626892b

*/
```